# Global name is not defined executing a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm coding a project, in which I have 2 files (dataStructure.py and calculUser.py) working together and 1 which is a test file.

In `structureDonnees.py` I have this function which reads a dataset containing cars and builds data structures :

```
# -*-encoding:utf-8-*-

import csv
import sys #pour utiliser maximum et minimum du type float
from calculUser import *
from trajetUser import *


def recupVoiture() :

#nom de la base de donnée
nomFichier = 'CO2_passenger_cars_v10.csv'
#on ouvre le fichier en lecture
opener = open(nomFichier, "r")
#On ouvre le fichier nomFichier en lecture
lectureFichier = csv.reader(opener, delimiter='\t')
#le dico contenant les carburants
fuelType = dict()
#le dico contenant les voitures
voiture = dict()
#le dico contenant les émissions de CO2 en g/km
emission = dict()
#minimum et maximum emission
min_emission = sys.float_info.max #initialisé à max(float) pour que l'on soit sûr que toutes les emissions soient plus petites
max_emission = sys.float_info.min #initialisé à min(float) pour que l'on soit sûr que toutes les emissions soient plus grandes


for row in lectureFichier :
    #Si la colonne existe
    if row:
        #construction du dictionnaire voiture
        if voiture.has_key(row[10]) : 
            if row[11].upper() not in voiture[row[10]] : voiture[row[10]].append("%s" %row[11].upper()) #on ajoute le modèle
        else :
            voiture[row[10]] = [] #on crée une liste vide contenant les modèles et leurs versions
            voiture[row[10]].append("%s" %row[11]) #on ajoute le modèle et sa version

        #construction du dictionnaire fuelType
        if fuelType.has_key(row[10]) : fuelType[row[10]].append(row[19].upper()) #ajout du type de carburant utilisé par la voiture correspondante dans voiture{}
        else : 
            fuelType[row[10]] = [] #on crée une liste vide contenant les carburants
            fuelType[row[10]].append(row[19]) #ajout du type de carburant utilisé par la voiture correspondante dans voiture{}

        #construction du dictionnaire emission
        if emission.has_key(row[10]) : 
            emission[row[10]].append(row[14]) #ajout de la quantité de CO2 émise par la voiture correspondante dans voiture{}
            min_emission = minEmission(float(row[14]), min_emission)
            max_emission = maxEmission(float(row[14]), max_emission)
        else : 
            emission[row[10]] = [] #on crée une liste vide contenant les émissions en CO2
            fuelType[row[10]].append(row[14]) #ajout de la quantité de CO2 émise par la voiture correspondante dans voiture{}
            min_emission = minEmission(float(row[14]), min_emission)
            max_emission = maxEmission(float(row[14]), max_emission)

#On ferme le fichier
opener.close()
#La valeur de retour est un tableau contenant les structures de données générées.
res = [voiture, fuelType, emission, min_emission, max_emission]
return res
```

In the `calculUser.py`, I defined the `minEmission` and `maxEmission` function :

```
def minEmission(emissionFichier, min_emission) :

     if emissionFichier < min_emission :
        min_emission = emissionFichier

    return min_emission


def maxEmission(emissionFichier, max_emission) :

    if emissionFichier > max_emission :
        max_emission = emissionFichier

    return max_emission
```

When I'm executing `test.py`, I get an error with this line :

```
table = recupVoiture()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
tableau = recupVoiture()
File "/home/user/Polytech/ge3/ProjetPython/structureDonnees.py", line 60, in recupVoiture
min_emission = minEmission(float(row[14]), min_emission)
NameError: global name 'minEmission' is not defined
```

I don't understand why I get this error. By executing everything except `test.py` I get no error but when I do it doesn't execute due to this `minEmission` and `maxEmission` not defined.

Is it because I'm calling a function when I'm defining a function?
How could I fix it?

Comment: BTW, python has `min` and `max`, there is no need to rewrite it

Comment: The indentation is broken, so it's hard to be sure, but are you defining two variables inside one function and expecting them to be available in a different function in a *completely different script?* Not only is that not going to work, consider for a moment just how difficult it would be to figure out what a program was doing in a world where that did work.

Comment: Fix your identation, and while you're at it make sure that you create a minimal, complete, verifiable, example(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - we should be able to cut the snippets and copy into the named files and run it through python and get the same error as you.

Comment: it says the exception happens in `structureDonnees.py`. I cant see its code anywhere around, so I just assume you're missing an `import` in that file

Comment: I can't use min() and max() because I need to look for in a dictionnary containing lists which contains the values I'm looking for.

Should I put the entire files so you can see all my code ? Or should I put the imports and functions ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm defining min_emission and max_emission so they take the return value of minEmission() and maxEmission(). Those variables are declared in recupVoiture(), minEmission and maxEmission are both calculating functions which are in a file containing exclusively calculs (calculUser.py)

Comment: *"Should I put the entire files so you can see all my code ?"*, no we want a [mcve]

Comment: I agree with @yedpodtrzitko, you should be importing `minEmission` and `maxEmission` from `calculUser`.  Something like `from calculUser import minEmission, maxEmission` needs to be present in `structureDonnees.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, it seems like my functions `minEmission()` and `maxEmission()` couldn't do a reference to `max_emission` and `min_emission` since those variables are declared in `structureDonnees.py` and not in `calculUser.py`.

I fixed it by creating an intermediary variable which takes the value of `min_emission` and `max_emission` and which is returned, instead of `min_emission` and `max_emission`.

Plus, I had to do a : `from calculUser import minEmission, maxEmission`directly in the `recupVoiture()` function. I know that's awful but it solved the problem. I'll use it until I find a better, cleaner solution.

Thanks for the help guys, I'll do a better post/code if I have to ask any other help ! :)

Comment: how that is awful? what is awful is that you do `import *` that is bad practice and can generate more problems that not, say for example that module `a` and `b` both has a function name `foo` that do different (or similares) thing, if you do `import *` from both modules if you call foo you may end with the wrong foo, not only that, but 6 month later if you visite your code again and see a `foo` you will not know where it come from, or worse say you don't know that one of them has its own foo, you may en using that and your code do something unexpected and you will not know why...